# C++ Force Inheritance for some types

Tags: c++, inheritance

In Rust programming language, you can define a trait for generic types with special specs.
(for those who may does not know, imagine `trait` like `base class` and `implementing` like `inheriting`.)
for example, I define a trait named `General` and implement it for all types that implements trait `Debug` as below:

```rs
// here we implement `General` trait with its only one member `general` for
// all types that implement trait `Debug` 
impl<T: Debug> General for T {
    fn general() {
        println!("GENERAL!");
    }
}
```

I'm looking for such property in c++. can I force some classes to inherit from an special class?

**More explanations**:
why I'm looking for this because I implemented a class named `Mover` and this class is base of all `Movable` objects. this class provides necessary checks and methods for moving objects. so I need that an std class for example, inherits from my class, because some of my other classes has type constraints for their types that they must derived from `Mover` and I want to use that std classes in my classes. for example, I have an `Arc` class that is an smart pointer with counter of referencing and dereferencing. so types passing to this object must be `Movable`:

```cpp
template<Movable MovableData>
class Arc: Mover {
    MovableData* inner;
    Size         counter;

    // stuff...
};
```

now I want to create an Arc from `std::vector<int>` for example but with this, it is impossible. any idea?

Comment: In C++20, you have this - it's called `requires`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do in C++ is require that in order for some operation (say calling a particular function) to work the arguments must meet particular criteria. The easiest example of such criteria is the argument types themselves, but with older-style SFINAE and newer-style concepts you can also require more.

For example, you can have a function that takes a "std::vector const &" argument but you can also use those techniques to require that T is derived from a particular type, or implements a member with a given name and signature.

You cannot, in general, force type derivation independent of how the derived type is used. That is, you cannot have

```
class` MyBase {...};
```

that somehow specifies that not-yet-defined types must derive from it.